# Vue.js + PHP Select Input does not persist on submit

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, vue.js

My "issue" is actually ignorance. I have an HTML form and I use **Vue.js** to fill a `v-select` input with PHP data:

```
<div id="app">
    <form>
        <v-select name="user2_id" placeholder="Seleccionar Usuario" :options="[{!! $users !!}]" class="select"></v-select>
        <select name="user2_type" id="user2_type" class="form-control required">
        ...
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

The JS part:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.1.10"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-select@2.0.0"></script>
<script>
    Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect);

    new Vue({
        el: '#app'
    });
</script>
```

When I submit the form I only got the **user2_type** but not the **user2_id**. I think is because the browser does not recognize `v-select` as a form input.

Is there any easy way or should I submit the form with AJAX or something else?

Thank you

**Edit: Web Inspector generated HTML output**

```
<div class="dropdown v-select select searchable" name="user2_id">
    <div type="button" class="dropdown-toggle clearfix">
        <input debounce="0" placeholder="Seleccionar Usuario" class="form-control" style="width: 100%;" type="search">
        <i role="presentation" class="open-indicator"></i>
        <div class="spinner" style="display: none;">
            Loading...
        </div>
    </div><!---->
</div>
```

Comment: Look in your browser's web inspector at the generated code for the `<v-select>`. Does it include a `<select>` with a `name` parameter? I don't see a `name` parameter in the docs at http://sagalbot.github.io/vue-select/

Comment: @ceejayoz, thanks for replying. I added the generated HTML in web inspector. It doesn't contain a select or a name either.

Comment: There's your answer, then. Typically, a Vue component would submit its data via an AJAX request, not a standard form submission, which is probably why vue-select isn't really set up for your use case. You'll probably need to populate a hidden field with the value of the vue-select.

Comment: okay then, reply it as an answer and I will mark it as correct. Thank you.

Comment: There he asks the same: https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select/issues/145

Answer (score 3, accepted):

vue-select does not create an actual `<select>` field, as in Vue components any form submissions are typically processed via AJAX, not a standard `<form>` POST.

You'll need to get the value out of the `<v-select>` - there are a couple of ways.

- Use a `onChange` callback (see [the docs](https://sagalbot.github.io/vue-select/)) to update a field manually.
- Use v-model to update a hidden field simultaneously with the value.

  > ```
  > <v-select v-model="user2_id"></v-select>
  > <input type="hidden" v-model="user2_id">
  > ```